# How do the operators `{@@}` and `{##}` differ in the Moodle STACK system?

Tags: variables, operators, moodle

What the title says. I've ran into these operators before when authoring a question and looking at questions others have made, but I can't seem to find what the actual specific difference is. The difference is not mentioned anywhere in the documentation, that I can find. I know that `{@var@}` is used to display the value of the variable `var` specified previously in the form in the question text, but what would `{#var#}` do?

Is there anybody here who knows about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll find the answer on the [CASText documentation](https://github.com/maths/moodle-qtype_stack/blob/master/doc/en/Authoring/CASText.md) page in the qtype-stack source repository.

In both cases, whatever is enclosed is evaluated by CAS, but (if I understand the doc correctly) when using `{@ ... @}` the result is displayed in LaTeX, while `{# ... #}` is displayed in Maxima.